# Why won't Git Bash upload some of my photos?

Tags: git, github

I have images in a folder, of which I then upload to github.com via Git Bash. Some of the images don't upload no matter what I seem to do. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` in the folder? What is the size of the images in question? If you are on a Linux or macOS, can you please add the output of `ls -lh` to the question?

Comment: I looked for the ".gitignore", but couldn't find it. Where is it supposed to be located? The dimensions of one of the images is 600x450, with a size of 304 KB. I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: The `.gitignore` file, if present, should be located at the root of your git repository. File size shouldn’t be an issue. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Can you please share the output of `git status`?

Comment: Aside from files for the website, there is only a ".git" folder in the root directory of the folder. Git Status shows: "$ git status; On branch master; nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "upload"? Can you share the specific sequence of commands you used to do the upload?

Comment: Sure, when I upload via Git Bash, I type in "git add ." + "git commit -m "changes" + "git push origin master".

Comment: @Weebs Could you show us what `git push origin master` says? [Edit them into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60590914/edit), please.

Comment: To see the ignored files, you can use `git status --ignored`. To check if a file is ignored and where the pattern is configured, use `git check-ignore -v <filepath>`.

Comment: Note there are also multiple places where .gitignore can be defined. As stated before it can be in the root level of your repo, but it can also be in your users home directory, and at the system level (where git is installed). It works in the same way npm does in sort of a cascade lookup.